# LINQPad Hiding Entities with POCO Connection

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, dbcontext, linqpad

When I connect LINQPad to my custom assembly using POCO connection, I'm missing some of my entities. This is a project was handed off to me, so I'm not sure what exactly causes this.

This is what I see in LINQPad for my FooContext,

[image: FooContext]

This is my project model,

[image: Model]

This is a table that does not show up in LINQPad,

```
[Table("People")]
public class Person : DomainEntity
{
    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public String GivenName { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(50)]
    public String Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhysicalAddress> PhysicalAddresses { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CompanyContact> CompanyContacts { get; set; }
}
```

Here's a table that does,

```
[Table("Tags")]
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
    public virtual DomainEntity Entity { get; set; }
}
```

What determines what LINQPad shows for FooContext?

Answer (score 1):

LINQPad uses the following logic to determine which entities to display in the Schema Explorer:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter adapter = this;
var items = adapter.ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems (DataSpace.CSpace);
var container = (EntityContainer) items.First (i => i.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityContainer);
var entities = container.BaseEntitySets.Where (b => b.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntitySet && b.ElementType != null && b.ElementType is EntityType);
entities.Dump(1);
```

Does your table show up when you run this code in LINQPad with your custom POCO data context selected?

Comment: I have the same problem, I try to run above the code but my entities still not shown up. Kindly advise